# Issues with calling variables on a function and the package lubridate

Tags: r, function, date, time, lubridate

I am starting with package creation and I am not that fluent in making functions (at least complex ones). I have created the following function in my package (uploading dependencies such as lubridate, readr, dplyr and tidyr.

```
read_tag <- function(tagfile, type, time_var = NULL, date_var, delim = ",") {

  if (type == "argos") {

    data <- readr::read_delim(file = tagfile, col_names = T, delim = delim)

    data <- data %>%
      tidyr::separate(date_var, c("Day", "Month", "Year"), sep = "-") %>%
      dplyr::mutate(hour = lubridate::hour(as.character(time_var)), minutes = lubridate::minute(as.character(time_var))) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(date = as.Date(lubridate::ymd(paste(Year, Month, Day, sep = "-")))) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(date_time = lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(date, time_var, sep = ""))) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(year_day = lubridate::yday(date))

  } else if (type == "internal") {

    data = readr::read_delim(file = tagfile, col_names = T, col_types = readr::cols(), delim = delim, quote = "#")

    data$date_var <- as.POSIXct(x = data$date_var, origin = "1970-01-01")

    data <- dplyr::mutate(data, year = lubridate::year(date_var), month = lubridate::month(date_var, label = TRUE), day = lubridate::day(date_var),
                   hour = lubridate::hour(date_var), minutes = lubridate::minute(date_var), seconds = lubridate::second(date_var), week = lubridate::week(date_var), day_number = lubridate::yday(date_var), dn = ifelse(hour >= 9 & hour < 21, "Day", "Night"))

  }
}
```

So, in essence I want to load a particular file and make some date/time manipulations from existing variables in the file I am loading (for now you can ignore the second part of the function- after if else). I receive the following errors depending how I call the function:

- Calling time_var and date_var without quotes:

```
read_tag(tagfile = "path/to/file.csv", type = "argos", time_var = Time, date_var = Day, delim = ",")

 Error: object 'Day' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

- Calling time_var and date_var as strings:

```
read_tag(tagfile = "../../03_Atlantic-Cod-Psat/data/100987-Series.csv", type = "argos", time_var = "Time", date_var = "Day", delim = ",")

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `hour`.
i `hour = lubridate::hour(as.character(time_var))`.
x character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The funny thing of the second error, is that if I read the file just with read_delim, the time variable is called as a time vector and I can work with it with lubridate functions. So I guess my questions are: why is there a difference when quoting the values for the variables, why is the function not understanding the class of the time_var, when it is actually loaded as a time vector?

Thank you

Session info:

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042), RStudio 1.4.1106

Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
  LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

Package version:
  askpass_1.1          assertthat_0.2.1     bit_4.0.4            bit64_4.0.5          brew_1.0.6          
  brio_1.1.2           cachem_1.0.6         callr_3.7.0          cli_3.0.1            clipr_0.7.1         
  commonmark_1.7       compiler_4.1.1       cpp11_0.4.0          crayon_1.4.1         credentials_1.3.1   
  curl_4.3.2           DBI_1.1.1            desc_1.3.0           devtools_2.4.2       diffobj_0.3.4       
  digest_0.6.27        dplyr_1.0.7          ellipsis_0.3.2       evaluate_0.14        fansi_0.5.0         
  fastmap_1.1.0        fs_1.5.0             generics_0.1.0       gert_1.4.1           gh_1.3.0            
  GINR.Psat_0.0.0.9000 gitcreds_0.1.1       glue_1.4.2           graphics_4.1.1       grDevices_4.1.1     
  highr_0.9            hms_1.1.1            httr_1.4.2           ini_0.3.1            jsonlite_1.7.2      
  knitr_1.34           lifecycle_1.0.1      lubridate_1.7.10     magrittr_2.0.1       memoise_2.0.0       
  methods_4.1.1        mime_0.11            openssl_1.4.5        pillar_1.6.3         pkgbuild_1.2.0      
  pkgconfig_2.0.3      pkgload_1.2.2        praise_1.0.0         prettyunits_1.1.1    processx_3.5.2      
  progress_1.2.2       ps_1.6.0             purrr_0.3.4          R6_2.5.1             rappdirs_0.3.3      
  rcmdcheck_1.3.3      Rcpp_1.0.7           readr_2.0.1          rematch2_2.1.2       remotes_2.4.0       
  rlang_0.4.11         roxygen2_7.1.2       rprojroot_2.0.2      rstudioapi_0.13      rversions_2.1.1     
  sessioninfo_1.1.1    stats_4.1.1          stringi_1.7.4        stringr_1.4.0        sys_3.4             
  testthat_3.0.4       tibble_3.1.4         tidyr_1.1.3          tidyselect_1.1.1     tools_4.1.1         
  tzdb_0.1.2           usethis_2.0.1        utf8_1.2.2           utils_4.1.1          vctrs_0.3.8         
  vroom_1.5.5          waldo_0.3.1          whisker_0.4          withr_2.4.2          xfun_0.26           
  xml2_1.3.2           xopen_1.0.0          yaml_2.2.1           zip_2.2.0
```

Comment: The issue is (probably) that dplyr verbs use [tidy evaluation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). If you want to pass your variable names as strings you could make use of the `.data` pronoun, e.g. try `.data[[time_var]]` inside your function. Otherwise if you want to pass the variable names without quotes you have to embrace the arguments using e.g. curly-curly `{{`, i.e.  use `{{ time_var }}` inside your function.

Comment: You were right. I will have to learn more about that. More informally now, do you know of good resources for good practices in functions and packages creation?
I used the curly notation btw.

Thank you

Comment: Stefan, could you please post that as the answer?